# Recursive CTE generating extra record

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I have following Recursive SQL query to generate all dates for any month provided in a date.

It always generate extra date(1st of next month).

```
DECLARE @currentDate DATE = '2016-5-25';
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(DAY, @currentDate) + 1, @currentDate) AS  firstDay
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, firstDay) 
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, firstDay) = DATEPART(MONTH, @currentDate)
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you are using

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 (X64) 
 Jun  9 2015 12:06:16 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Recursive CTE`, the recursive query will be first executed then the Where clause is validated

Here is the correct way

```
DECLARE @currentDate DATE = '2016-5-25';

;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT dateadd(dd,1,eomonth(@currentDate,-1)) AS  fd
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, fd) 
    FROM cte
    WHERE fd < eomonth(@currentDate)
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

Instead you can use tally table to do this which is way better in performance when compared to `Recursive CTE`

```
;WITH e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), -- 10
e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b), -- 10*10
e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e2), -- 10*100
tally as (SELECT id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) FROM e3 )
select 
dateadd(DD,ID-1,dateadd(dd,1,eomonth(@currentDate,-1))) as Dates
from Tally
where dateadd(DD,ID-1,dateadd(dd,1,eomonth(@currentDate,-1)))<=eomonth(@currentDate)
```